# Page composer is not showing in HCL commerce store 9.1 Emerald store

Tags: frameworks, commerce, hcl, emerald-framework

I am working on HCL commerce 9.1 ,We are able to enable the Page composer for arrora store (Default),But we are not able to enable the Page composer for emerald store,How to enable the Page composer for emerald store.Any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give enough detail to answer your question. You are confusing composers, there are two, commerce composer which is used with the aurora store. Then there is the page composer for react based stores. This was released in 9.1.7, you didn't specify which version you are using. To make page composer work in the development environment, you need to download the react server and install and configure it in the toolkit. Here is a link to the instructions:
https://help.hcltechsw.com/commerce/9.1.0/install/tasks/t91storesdk.html